# How to hide footer from the homepage in wordpress website

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to hide the footer on my wordpress website through css but now it starts to looking weird instead of getting disable.

> http://texmex-cantina.com

Here is the website and i want to hide footer from this main landing page only.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your custom css file.

Write the following:

```
.page-id-1979 footer {
  display: none !important;
}
```

The `.page-id-1979` is the class of your landing page and we want to remove the `footer` in that page only.

Comment: it worked for me but now i can see a white space under the image and on the different pages there is also white space showing under the footer. any idea how that can be resolved?

Comment: I don't see that whitespace you're talking about in my end. Perhaps you can provide a screenshot?

Comment: this space is on the sub-pages http://prntscr.com/k8q4s4

Comment: and this is on the main page mobile view http://prntscr.com/k8q55s

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache? I really don't see it here: https://snag.gy/61Vj3X.jpg

Comment: yes i did sir, Try to view it on mobile you will see white line under the main landing page image and try to view the site on different screen i guess

Comment: I visited the site using my phone (Samsung Galaxy S5). And this is the result: https://snag.gy/uPqiF6.jpg Maybe you could ask other people to check your site on their end.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the home page .php file for example index.php

then open that file and remove or comment

this way footer will be remove for individual page.

Answer (score 0):

In the css file, set attribute display of the div you want to hide to none, Like this

```
.whatever-your-class{
  ...
  display:none;
  ...
}
```

you can even do something like this

```
<footer style="display:none;" .. >
```

Comment: it worked for me but now i can see a white space under the image and on the different pages there is also white space showing under the footer.  how that can be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use javascript/Jquery to hide the "footer-wrapper-area" class.
Add Jquery script source in your html code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then add the code below in your index.html page.

```
<script>
$('.footer-wrapper-area').css("visibility","hidden");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress set body classes automatically through the `body_class()` function, and it assign the `.home` class for any page you setup as Front Page, so apply display none to your `.home footer`, so no matters of the page ID of your front page, the CSS rule will work.

```
.home footer {
    display: none !important;
}
```

See docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/

Also you can hide it from the DOM by set a if statement using the WordPress function `is_front_page()`, see docs:https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page

```
<?php if(!is_front_page()): ?>
   <footer>
     [...]
   </footer>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: it worked for me but now i can see a white space under the image and on the different pages there is also white space showing under the footer. any idea how that can be resolved?